# Why does std::regex_iterator cause a stack overflow with this data?

Tags: c++, regex, c++11

I've been using `std::regex_iterator` to parse log files.  My program has been working quite nicely for some weeks and has parsed millions of log lines, until today, when today I ran it against a log file and got a stack overflow.  It turned out that just one log line in the log file were causing the problem.  Does anyone know know why my regex is causing such massive recursion?  Here's a small self contained program which shows the issue (my compiler is VC2012):

```
#include <string>
#include <regex>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

std::wstring test = L"L3  T15356 79726859 [CreateRegistryAction] Creating REGISTRY Action:\n"
                L"  Identity: 272A4FE2-A7EE-49B7-ABAF-7C57BEA0E081\n"
                L"  Description: Set Registry Value: \"SortOrder\" in Key HKEY_CURRENT_USER\\Software\\Hummingbird\\PowerDOCS\\Core\\Plugins\\Fusion\\Settings\\DetailColumns\\LONEDOCS1\\Search Unsaved\\$AUTHOR.FULL_NAME;DOCSADM.PEOPLE.SYSTEM_ID\n"
                L"  Operation: 3\n"
                L"  Hive: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\n"
                L"  Key: Software\\Hummingbird\\PowerDOCS\\Core\\Plugins\\Fusion\\Settings\\DetailColumns\\LONEDOCS1\\Search Unsaved\\$AUTHOR.FULL_NAME;DOCSADM.PEOPLE.SYSTEM_ID\n"
                L"  ValueName: SortOrder\n"
                L"  ValueType: REG_DWORD\n"
                L"  ValueData: 0\n"
                L"L4  T15356 79726859 [CEMRegistryValueAction::ClearRevertData] [ENTER]\n";

int wmain(int argc, wchar_t* argv[])
{
    static wregex rgx_log_lines(
        L"^L(\\d+)\\s+"             // Level
        L"T(\\d+)\\s+"              // TID
        L"(\\d+)\\s+"               // Timestamp
        L"\\[((?:\\w|\\:)+)\\]"     // Function name
        L"((?:"                     // Complex pattern
          L"(?!"                    // Stop matching when...
            L"^L\\d"                // New log statement at the beginning of a line
          L")"                      
          L"[^]"                    // Matching all until then
        L")*)"                      // 
        );

    try
    {
        for (std::wsregex_iterator it(test.begin(), test.end(), rgx_log_lines), end; it != end; ++it)
        {
            wcout << (*it)[1] << endl;
            wcout << (*it)[2] << endl;
            wcout << (*it)[3] << endl;
            wcout << (*it)[4] << endl;
            wcout << (*it)[5] << endl;
        }
    }
    catch (std::exception& e)
    {
        cout << e.what() << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The complex pattern part seems to be causing it. Don't know why though.

Comment: I bet it's fine in perl, I don't quite trust `std::regex` yet.

Comment: @Benj Wut? FUD. It can be an exponentially misbehaving regex. Most often it is about nested kleene stars. Try using non-greedy matches and or using `+` instead of `*` where possible. Also watch out with optionals in repeated groups. Best advice... Start small. Build step-by-step. Test your regex each step.

Comment: @Benj in all fairness, GCC apparently doesn't support this style of iteration _at all_ yet :(

Comment: @sehe Yes, I will MS some credit, regex is one area were they've worked hard and are actually ahead of the game.  Although gcc is ahead in most other parts of C++11.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Negative lookahead patterns which are tested on every character just seem like a bad idea to me, and what you're trying to do is not complicated. You want to match (1) the rest of the line and then (2) any number of following (3) lines which start with something other than L\d (small bug; see below): (another edit: these are regexes; if you want to write them as string literals, you need to change `\` to `\\`.)

```
 .*\n(?:(?:[^L]|L\D).*\n)*
 |   |  |
 +-1 |  +---------------3
     +---------------------2
```

In Ecmascript mode, `.` should not match \n, but you could always replace the two `.`s in that expression with `[^\n]`

Edited to add: I realize that this may not work if there is a blank line just before the end of the log entry, but this should cover that case; I changed `.` to `[^\n]` for extra precision:

```
 [^\n]*\n(?:(?:(?:[^L\n]|L\D)[^\n]*)?\n)*
```

Comment: Well done ;-)  This works, it didn't occur to me that this could be done without a negative lookahead.

Comment: It's worth pointing out for posterity, I did need to use `[^\n]` as you suggested.

Comment: @Benj That's good to know; I don't have VC kicking around to try it with. I presume from the fact that you use `[^]` to mean "any character" that [^L] will actually match an empty line as well. In case this happens, I'm editing with a small modification.

Comment: @Benj, that's probably because on windows a blank line actually has a \r in it. I guess.

Answer (score 1):

The regex appears to be OK; at least there is nothing in it that could cause catastrophic backtracking.

I see a small possibility to optimize the regex, cutting down on stack use:

```
static wregex rgx_log_lines(
    L"^L(\\d+)\\s+"             // Level
    L"T(\\d+)\\s+"              // TID
    L"(\\d+)\\s+"               // Timestamp
    L"\\[([\\w:]+)\\]"          // Function name
    L"((?:"                     // Complex pattern
      L"(?!"                    // Stop matching when...
        L"^L\\d"                // New log statement at the beginning of a line
      L")"                      
      L"[^]"                    // Matching all until then
    L")*)"                      // 
    );
```

Did you [set the ECMAScript option](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/syntax_option_type)? Otherwise, I suspect the regex library defaults to POSIX regexes, and those don't support lookahead assertions.

Comment: Sadly `std::regex` has no concept of a multiline regex (unlike perl).  So `.` can't be used across lines and `^` and `$` do mean the start/end of line.  These anchors actually change in perl depending on whether you're in single/multi line mode.

Comment: @Benj: Ah, OK, well then that's good for this regex. I guess my version still causes a StackOverflow then?

Comment: I could be going blind :-) But what have you changed?  Isn't that regex the same?

Comment: I have removed the alternation `(?:\\w|\\:)` in favor of a charclass `[\\w:]`. But I've looked at the docs in the meantime - it might be that you need to set the ECMAScript option if you haven't done so already.

Comment: Ahh, yes!  Sadly I'm still getting the SO.  Interesting spot regarding the Ecmascript option.  I've tried it but it works the same.  The lookahead is definitely working without this option interestingly since I know that the expression works on all the other millions of log lines.

Comment: @TimPietzcker - the default for both `tr1::regex` and `std::regex` is ECMAScript. You have to ask for the POSIX stuff: basic, extended, grep, and awk.

Comment: @Benj - the default is ECMAScript.