# C++ 11 regex stack overflow / VS2012

Tags: c++, regex, visual-c++, c++11, visual-studio-2012

I'm in the process of converting some older Boost regex code to C++11, and I stumbled upon an issue with one of my test cases.  Here is a scenario which causes a stack overflow exception using std::regex, but worked fine with boost::regex.  I have not changed the regular expression pattern, and have verified the pattern is what I want.  It seems this particular string input fragment is causing the stack overflow.  Using VS2012, x64 debug build:

```
std::regex regx( "(^|\\})(([^\\{:])+:)+([^\\{]*\\{)" );

    const std::string testinput = " COLOR: #000; BACKGROUND-COLOR: #FFF; FONT-FAMILY: VERDANA, ARIAL, HELVETICA, SANS-SERIF; BACKGROUND:URL(URL(___FOO___)); BACKGROUND-2:URL(URL(___FOO___)); BORDER: 0 0 0 0; BORDER-2: 0 0 0; BORDER-3: 0 0; BORDER-4: 0PX; BORDER-5: 0.6; FILTER:PROGID:DXIMAGETRANSFORM.MICROSOFT.ALPHA(OPACITY=100); } ";
    std::smatch what;
    // this next line causes a stack overflow
    std::regex_search( testinput.cbegin(), testinput.cend(), what, regx );
```

Looking at the call stack after the exception, there seems to be some type of infinite recursion going on in the regex implementation.  I don't currently have GCC to test this with.  What am I doing wrong?

Update:
After the suggestions below, I pasted this code into a console app, VS 2012 x64 debug and I get the stack overflow.  If I change it to x64 release, or Win32 debug or release it runs fine.  Huh??? Do i need to reinstall VS and/or the platform SDK?  I'm on Win7 x64.

Update #2:
Somewhat related post:  [Why does std::regex_iterator cause a stack overflow with this data?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12828079/882436)
I suppose if I rewrite my regex, it might help.  I'm still not sure why the bitness matters though.  And why it works for others, but not for me on my system.  Sigh.

Comment: I'm not reproducing this crash in my installation of VS 2012 with a 64-bit debug build.  A direct copy of the code above, inside a `main` function, simply returns `false` from the call to `regex_search` - no match.

Comment: Works fine on mine (32-bit) as well.

Comment: @DanNissenbaum, thanks for confirming.  I updated my question; seems to only happen in x64 debug.  x64 release or the Win32 builds run fine.  I don't get it?

Comment: Perhaps a clean solution (i.e., full rebuild)?

Comment: @DanNissenbaum -- done.  Same problem.   Ditto for my console app.  If I modify the regex pattern a little bit, it doesn't crash.  I'm just going to go with my revised regex and build in some extra exception handling to account for a potentially-buggy MS regex implementation.  Thanks for your input!

Comment: I'm also unable to reproduce this in my installation of VS 2012. Looks to be specific to your app, or maybe to your some configuration settings within your project?

Comment: @KyleC -- yes, could be.  I'm guessing it's my installation somehow, as I get the same behavior in my app and with a fresh console app with default settings.  I have all of the Win7 and VS updates.  FML!

Answer (score 2):

I've been reproduced this with x64 debug build, and I belive this is a real **stack overflow**.

When you change your stack size to 10MB or so (linker command line option `/STACK:"10000000"`),
it will work fine.

Comment: Thanks, I agree this is a valid workaround.  Makes me wonder, though, if this is the actual solution, or just a way to cover up defects in <regex>, especially since boost regex runs fine in the same app.  Since release mode apparently reuses the stack, it shouldn't be a problem I suppose...thanks again

Comment: I think this is a some kind of defect.
I've not investigate the `<regex>` code,
but even x86/Release very simple regex pattern will cause stack overflow.
Please check this:
`using namespace std; regex r("(x)+"); string t(512, 'x'); regex_search(t, r);`

Comment: Yes, I can reproduce the same problem in x86 and x64 debug and release modes.  Interesting...