# Stack overflow caused by backtracking in regular expression

Tags: c++, regex, c++11, stack-overflow, backtracking

I want to match a string using the following regular expression with C++11 using std::regex:

```
([^;]|'[^']*')*
```

What I am trying to achieve is the following: I want to match all characters except the semicolon, however, the semicolon should be ignored if enclosed by apostrophes (this denotes a string). When trying to apply the regular expression I get a stack overflow. I realize that the problem is caused by [excessive backtracking](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17699238/2440501). Unfortunately, I don't know how to get rid of the problem. How can the expression be rewritten such that it does not cause loads of backtracking?

Minimal code example with a dummy text:

```
#include <regex>
#include <string>
int main()
{
    std::string str = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed ut suscipit enim. Praesent varius purus ac sem vulputate pulvinar. Mauris scelerisque arcu tortor, at bibendum dui rhoncus ut. Nunc dictum malesuada condimentum. Mauris ornare nunc eget efficitur tempor. Morbi ex nibh, consectetur vitae bibendum id, bibendum varius purus. Proin finibus quam vel ornare molestie. Mauris condimentum nisi efficitur, fringilla massa ut, commodo diam. Mauris lobortis laoreet magna sed commodo. Donec faucibus lectus placerat ex pulvinar interdum.";
    std::regex rgx("([^;]|'[^']*')*");
    std::regex_match(std::begin(str), std::end(str), rgx); // Stack overflow!
    return 0;
}
```

I am using Visual Studio 2012.

Comment: not really sure what is the problem, but you can try like, non-capture `(?:[^;]|'[^']*')*`, and tweak regex a bit, `(?:''|'[^']+'|[^;])*`

Comment: @YOU: I have tried the non-capture grouping already, no success. The little tweak you suggested didn't do the job either.

Comment: how about with `+` instead of `*`?, it changed the regex, and wont match blank string but you can try.

Comment: @YOU It still causes the stack overflow.

Comment: You could try using [RE2](https://github.com/google/re2).

Comment: someone did work by increasing stack limit - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15696435/c-11-regex-stack-overflow-vs2012

Comment: @YOU: I saw that post, but I got the feeling that I am doing something fundamentally wrong here. Replacing my initial expression by `([^;])*` causes already the stack overflow.
@KerrekSB: I feel that such a (fairly simple) task should be possible with the standard implementation.

Comment: That regex doesn't make use of backtracking. It's best if you force the scanner to go through the second part of the `|` operator, as this regex will accept `Lorem 'Ipsum; and no ending apostropho`.  Use `([^;']|'[^']*')*` as your regex, explicitly excluding the apostropho in the first part of the first group.

Answer (score 2):

If you switch the regex grammar to basic posix instead of deafult ECMAscript, it will no longer overflow:

```
std::regex rgx("([^;]|'[^']*')*", std::regex_constants::basic);
```

I tested with MSVC2013 and it works.  Unfortunately, it will not match your expectations either, as demonstrates this small variant:

```
...
std::smatch cm;
std::regex_search(str, cm, rgx, std::regex_constants::match_any | std::regex_constants::match_continuous | std::regex_constants::match_not_null); // No overflow!
for (int i = 0; i < cm.size(); i++)
    std::cout << "Found:" << cm[i];  // but no result is printed out.
```

If choosing `std::regex_constants::extended` option, the stack overflow is back again.

If you test your regex with your data on **[RegExr](http://regexr.com/3aplu)** you will understand the problem:

[image]

The regex causes an infinity of potential matches.  As soon as you reduce the potential set of matches for example by putting a `;` after `Lorem` there is no stack overflow anymore.

This is indeed very unfortunate: no standard matching option (e.g. `std::regex_constants::match_any | std::regex_constants::match_continuous | std::regex_constants::match_not_null`) seems to take care of this frequent problem (e.g.: no "match largest").

Nevertheless, it remains related to the MSVC implementation of the standard library. This [online GCC example](http://ideone.com/M6KgVK) runs fine with the same expression. So  the **boost** or  **RE2** alternative could be worth to consider.

This code with boost 1.57 on MSVC2013, ran without any problem. As you see, it uses the same code/names as the standard, but replaces the `std` with `boost`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/regex.hpp>  // instead of <regex>
#include <string>
                            // use the boost alternative to std
using namespace boost::regex_constants;  
using boost::regex; using boost::smatch; using boost::regex_search;

int main()
{
    std::string str = "your very long string..." ;
    regex rgx("([^;]|'[^']*')*", extended | nosubs);
    smatch cm;
    //regex_match(str, cm, rgx, regex_constants:: match_continuous | match_not_null); // Stack overflow!
    regex_search(str, cm, rgx, match_continuous | match_not_null); 
    for (int i = 0; i < cm.size(); i++)
        std::cout << "Found:" << cm[i];
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @djf I din't see your post until I refreshed the screen.  However, I realized in the meantime that chaning the option is not sufficient, and that there is indeed a real problem with the VS implementation.

Comment: According to the syntax [definition of basic regex](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_03) you didn't use the correct syntax when you tested. From what I understand, parenthesis in BRE have to be escaped. When doing that I run into similar stack overflow issues.

Comment: @sven exactly:  in fact it accepts the regex (no exception raised), but there is no match, as the code above demonstrates.  So you have to use `extended` or the default grammar, and the MSVC implementation will hang, unless there is a very short match.  It's really an MSVC problem, as I copy/pasted the code to ideone to see it run succesfully with GCC.